# Dúvida na consulta de exercício sobre sql

Tags: sql

Tenho as seguintes relações:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O enunciado do exercício é:

Qual a média das notas atribuídas pelos professores por disciplina do curso
Geografia no 1º semestre de 2013. Apresentar o nome do
professor, a disciplina e a média. Ordenar pelo nome do professor.

Eu fiz a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT Professor.nome, Disciplina.nome, AVG(Aula.nota) as Media
FROM Aluno, Disciplina, Professor, Disciplina, DisciplinaCurso, Curso
WHERE DisciplinaCurso.NumDisp = Curso.NumDisp AND 
      DisciplinaCurso.NumDisp = Disciplina.NumDisp AND
      Aula.NumDisp = Disciplina.NumDisp AND Aula.NumFunc = Professor.NumFunc 
      AND Curso.Nome = 'Geografia' AND Aula.Semestre = '1º Semestre de 2013' 
GROUP BY Professor.nome, Disciplina.nome 
ORDER BY Professor.nome;
```

A dúvida minha é: do jeito que está minha consulta, ela está agrupando por nome de professores, e o exercício somente quer que agrupe por disciplina do curso, porém como vou conseguir retornar o nome desses professores sem agrupar? E ao invés de utilizar o INNER JOIN, essas junções com o WHERE será que vão dar certo?

Comment: as junções com inner join ou com `,` e condição no where, dão no mesmo, apenas muda a sintaxe. Particularmente, prefiro utilizar inner ou left join. Entendo que sua query está correta, pois se pede para exibir o nome do professor, a disciplina e média, o group by será pelo professor e pela disciplina.

Comment: @RovannLinhalis entendi cara.... bacana!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente desta forma:

```
SELECT PF.nome, DI.nome, AVG(AL.nota) as Media
FROM Aluno AL
LEFT OUTER JOIN Professor PF ON PF.NumFunc = AL.NumFunc
LEFT OUTER JOIN Disciplina DI ON DI.NumDisp = AL.NumDisp
LEFT OUTER JOIN DisciplinaCurso DC ON DC.NumDisp = DI.NumDisp
LEFT OUTER JOIN Curso CS ON CS.NumDisp = DC.NumDisp
WHERE CS.Nome = 'Geografia' AND AL.Semestre = '1º Semestre de 2013' 
GROUP BY DI.nome, PF.nome
ORDER BY DI.nome
```

(não testei porque nem tem como aqui ! rs)

```
Explicando por linha:

-- Define os campos a serem exibidos, com cálculo da média do campo "nota"
SELECT PF.nome, DI.nome, AVG(AL.nota) as Media
-- Aqui é sua tabela de pesquisa (tabela LEFT, esquerda)
FROM Aluno AL
-- Esses JOINS trás TUDO da sua tabela da "esquerda" (Aluno), mais os registros da sua tabela da "direita" (ex.: primeiro LEFT é a tabela Professor) que TEM VÍNCULO (relação) com a tabela da "esquerda" (Alunos)
LEFT OUTER JOIN Professor PF ON PF.NumFunc = AL.NumFunc
LEFT OUTER JOIN Disciplina DI ON DI.NumDisp = AL.NumDisp
LEFT OUTER JOIN DisciplinaCurso DC ON DC.NumDisp = DI.NumDisp
LEFT OUTER JOIN Curso CS ON CS.NumDisp = DC.NumDisp
-- Aqui você faz seus filtros
WHERE CS.Nome = 'Geografia' AND AL.Semestre = '1º Semestre de 2013'
-- Aqui você está agrupando
GROUP BY DI.nome, PF.nome
ORDER BY DI.nome
```

As vezes a sua confusão no entendimento, é por causa dos filtros e "agrupamento", porque você não enxerga as linhas.

Comment: vc utilizou o Left por algum motivo, porque se eu utiliza-se INNER JOIN não que daria na mesma, mas resolveria tbm certo?

Comment: Não, o INNER faria igual o que você fez pelo WHERE. 
Resumidamente: o INNER ele te trás tudo que for "VERDADEIRO" nas duas tabelas. Já o LEFT ele trás TUDO da sua tabela principal (left = esquerda) mesmo que a outra for vazia. e o RIGHT traria só o que for VERDADEIRO na tabela "da direita". Olhe esse link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UKp7.png

Comment: Nesse link acima, lembre-se: sempre sua tabela da consulta (FROM tabela) será "esquerda" = left, e as outras no JOIN, serão "direita" = right

Comment: Uma pergunta similar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/247921/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-join-e-where/247942#247942

Comment: entao mano, porém do jeito que tu faz ai, vai vim todos os elementos da esquerda.... isso que não entendi... porque tu quer que venha esses elementos da tabela da esquerda...  usando o JOIN.. vai filtrar apenas os que forem iguais e isto já nao me basta? ou é pelo fato de ter que fazer varios JOIN.. tu usou o left join

Comment: Vou adicionar explicando cada linha

Comment: @roanibz sim mano eu entendi... mas é que neste caso especifico se utilizar o inner join ou left join.. vai dar na mesma, inclusive... o left join pode retorna mais coisa que nao precisava.... pq com o JOIN vai retornar uma tabela que só satisfaz a condição, a intersecção delas..

Comment: A sim, por causa do seu GROUP e filtros ! `Dependendo da estrutura do seu banco`, até o `RIGHT JOIN` irá trazer igual, porque você está puxando com da tabela de aluno, que provavelmente sejam os registros finais. Aí vai de como são os registros do seu sistema. Mas precisando, estamos aqui !

Comment: tamo junto mano.. vlws demais pelo papo! :)