# Diferença entre INNER JOIN, JOIN e WHERE?

Tags: sql, join, where

Preciso realizar uma `query` que me retornem informações de acordo com determinada condição, sempre usei o `Where` por não saber se poderia usar outro método. Então qual a diferença entre `Where`, `Inner Join` e `Join`. Posso usar quando cada um deles?

Se puderem dar exemplos. Agradeço.

Comment: Melhor forma de entender: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UKp7.png

Comment: Melhor link para entender isso https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cara tem muito material sobre isso, mas essa imagem que mandei como comentário vai te ajudar melhor.

Basicamente você tem que entender o conceito da esquerda e direita (`left e right`), por exemplo:

A sua tabela em FROM ela é a sua tabela `esquerda`, ou seja, `left`, quando for fazer um JOIN.

```
FROM tabela1 X
LEFT OUTER JOIN tabela2 Y ON Y.campo1 = X.campo2
```

Ou seja, você está trazendo tudo da tabela X, mais os registros da Y que tem vínculo com a X.

Agora em:

```
FROM tabela1 X
RIGHT OUTER JOIN tabela2 Y ON Y.campo1 = X.campo2
```

Você trás tudo que está na sua tabela da `direita` "Y" mais os de "X" que tem relação com "Y".

O INNER somente o que for em comum nas 2 tabelas, e o FULL trás TUDO independente das relações.